# Xamarin - Constantly getting NSInvalidArgumentException on Button click

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm currently doing some cross-platform mobile development through Visual Studio using Xamarin (so in C#) and am about to start the iOS portion. I've never done iOS development before and thought I could get myself acquainted with their ["Hello, iOS" Tutorials.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS_multiscreen/hello,_iOS_multiscreen_quickstart/) Unfortunately, things have not been going smoothly. I constantly get NSInvalidArgumentExceptions from my TouchUpInside actions:

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.
Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason:
-[ViewController TranslateButton_TouchUpInside:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b6200d0
```

I can occasionally remedy it for a moment by literally remaking the Buttons, but it breaks pretty much right afterwards. The actual error itself occurs in my Main.cs file:

```
using UIKit;

namespace CheckinIOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"); //this line is where it breaks
        }
    }
}
```

In case it is any helpful, I am trying to deploy to iPhone 5S simulator running iOS 9.3 (but it breaks on iPhone 6 simulator as well). I could also post more of my code if necessary, but I copypasted all the C# from Xamarin's tutorial, and did the same thing as them for Main.storyboard.

I have spent a while looking for people with the same problem as me, but their solutions either did not work, or they got the error for slightly different reasons. Any assistance is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is my implementation of TranslateButton_TouchUpInside:

```
    TranslateButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            // Convert the phone number with text to a number
            // using PhoneTranslator.cs
            translatedNumber = PhoneTranslator.ToNumber(PhoneNumberText.Text);

            // Dismiss the keyboard if text field was tapped
            PhoneNumberText.ResignFirstResponder();

            if (translatedNumber == "")
            {
                CallButton.SetTitle("Call", UIControlState.Normal);
                CallButton.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                CallButton.SetTitle("Call " + translatedNumber, UIControlState.Normal);
                CallButton.Enabled = true;
            }
        };
```

Comment: Show your implementation of `TranslateButton_TouchUpInside:` from your `ViewController` class

Comment: I added my implementation. It was copypasted from Xamarin's tutorial

Comment: Your implementation doesn't match the method that your button is hooked up to.  Are you editing your method declaration after hooking up the button to your view controller?

Comment: I'm very new to iOS, so can you elaborate a bit on what that means? Xamarin's tutorial seems to tacitly assume the `TranslateButton.TouchUpInside` will work. How exactly would I go about hooking things up the right way?

Comment: I've never used xamarin so I don't know how it works honestly but in Xcode you can connect a button to a view controller and it will stub out the method for you in the format it expects.  Then if you change the method declaration to a format that it accepts but is different from the one it creates for you then it will cause your error until you re-create the connection.

Comment: Interesting. I will look into that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iOS Runtime is looking for a method called (in Obj-C land) `TranslateButton_TouchUpInside:` in your ViewController class. However there is no method exported to Obj-C with that name. A first guess is that you added an event to the button in the storyboard that perhaps had that name, but you either deleted that method or never implemented it.

Try opening your storyboard in iOS Designer and removing any event from the Properties->Events tab when your button is selected on the canvas. Also I assume your button has the name `TranslateButton` in the Properties->Widget pane when the button is selected on the canvas.

There are a couple ways to attach events to controls in Xamarin iOS. One, and the preferred way, is to create an event in iOS Designer for the control. If you do this, a partial method stub will be in the .designer.cs file with an Export attribute that exports the method name to the Obj-C runtime. You will then need to implement this method, using the same signature (without the Export Attribute), in your main .cs file for the ViewController. This is called, in Obj-C land, an `action`.

The other way is to do as is shown in your code snippet. In this case you ONLY need to give the control a name in the Properties->Widget pane that you can then use in code to subscribe to the TouchUpInside event. This is called, in Obj-C land, an `outlet`.

My guess is that you did both but without ever implementing the `TranslateButton_TouchUpInside:` method in your ViewController. Note that this is the Obj-C name used in the `Export` attribute of the method stub created in the `.designer.cs` file when you add an event to a control.

But it is hard to say without seeing the storyboard and both the main `ViewController.cs` file and the `ViewController.designer.cs` file

Comment: Oh, wow, thank you so much! Turns out that I had `TranslateButton_TouchUpInside` still listed as a `<connections><action>` in my storyboard's code. I must have double clicked the button and not realized it put that there.

Comment: Awesome, I am glad that helped!